# Multiple google search and output using bot

Tags: google-search

I have a large list of manufacture codes and I need to grab the product names for them, normally I would use google to search them one at a time and the search results usually have the product name but now I have 20,000 to convert :(

Does anyone know if there is a way to script this process and output to a text file the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following tasks:

1. Scrape the results from Google search for the search query you provide. For this script can be written in any language you know. But after certain no. of requests, Google will identify you as a bot and block you.
2. Another way is to use Google's [custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). You get first 20 results from google search in JSON or Atom format. You can then grab the result from there. Still you have limitations. Maximum no. of searches per day is 100 for a free user.